# How do I import a library from Github when the module is installed

Tags: 8, composer

I want to add https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib library to my module **Drupal 8** I try to add composer. json in the folder module but is not load when I installed module this is solution to upload this library without command "composer update "?

this is my **composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "drupal/googleads-php-lib",
  "description": "Integrates the googleads-php-lib library into Drupal",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "require": {
    "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "25.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

composer.json has no bearing when you enable a module in the Drupal admin. Drupal only looks at the `info.yml` of a module to ensure any listed dependency (module only) exists and has been met. Using `drush` also won't work. You need Composer for this.

You would need to require your module via `composer require drupal/mymodule` - at which point any dependencies listed in `require` would also be pulled in. For that to work, your module would need to be posted on drupal.org, with the [Drupal packages repository added to your root composer.json file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#drupal-packagist).

[You could also add a repository endpoint pointed at GitHub, Bitbucket or any other VCS service](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories), add a baseline composer.json file to your project and require it that way, too.

You can also do `composer require googleads/googleads-php-lib:25.0.0` from your Drupal root to pull in that package, but I would go the module route (so that package is always tied with the module).

Comment: Would it definitely need to be posted on Drupal.org? Is there a reason you couldn't point composer at a private repo to download a custom module? I guess there would be some effort involved to make it land in the right folder, but it kinda feels like composer would be able to handle that

Comment: You could also do that, sure. I guess the most generic approach would be a sandbox project on drupal.org, and you could offload it later to a private repo once you learn a bit more about Composer.

Comment: Yeah good point

Comment: Updated my answer, I literally just did that moments ago with a private pattern lab repo.

Comment: If it's a custom module for that site then adding the dependency to the main composer.json is fine. Or you can use the merge plugin like explained here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217810/loading-dependencies-from-the-vendor-directory-in-a-module-using-composer/217826#217826. merge plugin supports wildcards, so you can include all custom composer.json files with web/modules/custom/*/composer.json. If it should be a reusable module then any private or public git repository (e.g. github) should work, you just need to add a composer repository.